# How to trigger a radio button ONLY by clicking a select option

Tags: jquery, onclick, radio-button

I am looking to have a radio button that is ONLY triggered by the "onclick" of a select option. I do not want the user to be able to manually change the radio button. Is there a way to make this happen.  This is the code I have for the radio button to change (it works), but the user may still change it after the fact:

```
$("#button1").prop('checked',true);
$("#strategies").mouseup(function() {
    if(strat == $("#strategies").val()) {
        $("#button1").prop('checked',true);
        $("#why").hide();
        $("#whyNo").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#button2").prop('checked',true);
        $("#whyNo").hide();
        $("#why").show();
    }
```

});

html:

```
<input type="radio" id="button1" name="switch" value="0">No Switch<br>
<input type="radio" id="button2" name="switch" value="1">Switch<br>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of the HTML?

Comment: Does this work?
$('select').click(function (evt) {evt.preventDefault()});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, there's an attribute for input fields called disabled.  I'm not certain how to manipulate it in Javascript, however.

```
<input type="radio" disabled>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" disabled="disabled">
```

Keep in mind, some browsers may render it as "greyed out."

[w3schools input tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

[w3c recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled)

Comment: Oops, it looks like disabled would be appropriate for this instead...  editting.

Comment: disabled is a lot cleaner than disabled="disabled", but both are html5 compliant.  I updated the answer with a link to w3c's recommendations about disabled input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('input[name="switch"]').click(function () {
    return false;
});
```